# $\overline{xy8}$ is divisible by 7. Find the remainder of $10x + 15y + 21$ divided by $7$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:
$$\overline{xy8}\text{ is divisible by }7$$

Find the remainder of $10x + 15y + 21$ divided by $7$.

How can I do this? Any hint? Thank you!

I tried to write $\overline{xy8} = 100x + 10y + 8$ then division becomes: $(100x + 10y + 8) - 90x + 5y + 13$. But I can't find the remainder.

Comment: Hint: You can use the rule of divisibility of 7 for $\overline{xy8}$ then try to add some thing to get $10x + 15y +21$

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: You know that $7 \cdot 4 = 28$, so adding $7 \cdot 10$ each time to make the last digit $8$, $7 \cdot 14 = 98$ (too small) and $7 \cdot 24 = 168$. Thus $10(1) + 15(6) + 21 \equiv 10 + 15(-1) + 0 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$. Of course this might not be true for all such numbers, but assuming there is a unique answer, this must be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$100x + 10y + 8 \equiv (100-98x) + (10-7)y + 8-7 \equiv 2x +3y + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

and:

$$10x+15y+21 \equiv (10-7)x + (15-14)y + 21-21 \equiv 3x + y \equiv -4x-6y \pmod 7$$

so $-4x-6y \equiv -2(2x+3y+1) + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 3):

$100x+10y+8\equiv 2x+3y+1\pmod 7 $

$\Rightarrow  2x+3y+1\equiv 0\pmod 7$

$10x+15y+21\equiv 5(2x+3y)\equiv -5\equiv \boxed{2}\pmod 7$

Answer (score 2):

You have a good start and you can write $100x+10y+8=7n$ to express divisibility by $7$.

As a hint, what is the simplest expression you can find (on the left-hand side) which would be divisible by $7$? "Simplest" is a bit ambiguous, but look for small positive integers as coefficients/constants.